# Insert multiple symbols in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, symbols, library

Is there any plugin used to insert multiple symbols (external library symbols) to one artboard, rather than do it manually one by one?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a master Sketch file of all the symbols you want to use across multiple files.

1. Create a new sketch file and save all symbols there
2. Once you've created all your symbols in one Sketch file, go to `File > Add As Library`.
3. After you've saved that library, you can open up other sketch files
   and link that library file by going to `Preferences > Libraries`.

All your symbols will now be available (go to `Insert > Symbols` and you should see your new library and symbols there).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your answer. I already did that but I need to use 500 symbols from one library. I'm searching for some way to insert multiple symbols, rather than one by one...

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. There is this plugin: https://github.com/sonburn/symbol-instance-sheet which allows you to import ALL the symbols from a library into a new sheet. I'm not sure you can pick and choose which ones to place.

Comment: In fact the plugin import all the symbols. maybe there's no one for what I'm asking. than you :)